# incrementing time 15 minutes within loop

Tags: php

I want to create a dropdown that will take current time as start time and will end up till 24 hours, like till coming 24 hours so in between it will show time of every 15 minutes increment. The problem is that when I try to run the loop starting time is okay but with next loop the time jumps to 6 hours behind.

Here is my code:

```
$current_time = date('h:i A');
$end_hour     = date("+24 hours", $current_time);

echo "<option>" . $current_time . "</option>";  
for($i = 0; $i <= 96; $i++) {
    echo "<option>" . date("h:i A", $tNow) . "</option>";
    $tNow = strtotime('+15 minutes',$current_time);
}
```

Output coming as 
11:08 PM
4:00 PM
4:15 PM
4:30 PM

And so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for that:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$end = clone $now;
$end->modify("+24 hours");

while ($now <= $end) {
    echo "<option>" . $now->format('h:i A'). "</option>";
    $now->modify('+15 minutes');
}
```

Comment: using [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) you can copy an instantiated object without keeping the reference, so any update done on the cloned object will not affect the original one.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of things. First on your first line you are missing the second parameter. Then you are using $tNow undefined.

```
$current_time = date('h:i A', time());
$end_hour     = date("+24 hours", strtotime($current_time));


$tNow = strtotime($current_time);
echo "<option>" . $current_time . "</option>";  
for($i = 0; $i <= 96; $i++) {
    echo "<option>" . date("h:i A", $tNow) . "</option>";
    $tNow = strtotime('+15 minutes', $tNow);
}
```

Comment: The second parameter is optional. If not given then current date is used..